# JavaScript: How To Make An If Statement Do Two Things

Tags: javascript

Below is an extract from a piece of code:

```
if (lightColour === fileArray[0]) {
   lightColour = "RedOrangeLight.jpg";
   lightTimer = "5000";
}
```

Assuming that `lightColour` does equal `fileArray[0]`, what can I do to my code, so that `lightColour` equals `"RedOrangeLight.jpg"` and `lightTimer` is also assigned the value `"5000"`?

-- EDIT --

Okay, so clearly that wasn't very useful or helpful. I'll post my full code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Changing Traffic Lights w/ Arrays</h1>

<img id="trafficLight" src="RedLight.jpg">

<script>

var lightTimer = "1000"
var lightColour = trafficLight.src

var fileArray = ["RedLight.jpg",
                 "RedOrangeLight.jpg",
                 "GreenLight.jpg",
                 "OrangeLight.jpg"];

function lightChange() {

if (lightColour === fileArray[0]) {
   lightColour = "RedOrangeLight.jpg";
   lightTimer = 5000;
} else if (lightColour === fileArray[1]) {
   lightColour = "GreenLight.jpg";
   lightTimer = 1000;
} else if (lightColour === fileArray[2]) {
   lightColour = "OrangeLight.jpg";
   lightTimer = 5000;
} else {
  lightColour = "RedLight.jpg";
  lightTimer = 1000;
}

var light = document.getElementById('trafficLight');
light.src = lightColour

}

setInterval(lightChange, lightTimer);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any indication as to what I have done wrong?

Comment: Well. Exactly that.

Comment: what isn't working with your code? This seems right

Comment: Oh right... So I have done this part of my code correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your `setInterval` *timeout* only once - outside of your function. That's why it does not updates with the new *if/else* values!

**Solution:**
Use `setTimeout` **inside** your function in order to update your timeout values:

```js
var light = document.getElementById('trafficLight'); // Place it here!!
var lightTimer = 1000;
var lightColour = trafficLight.src;
var fileArray = [
  "//placehold.it/50x50/f00", // red
  "//placehold.it/50x50/f40", // redorange
  "//placehold.it/50x50/3f0", // green
  "//placehold.it/50x50/f80"  // orange
];

function lightChange() {

  if (lightColour === fileArray[0]) {
    lightColour = "//placehold.it/50x50/f40"; // redorange
    lightTimer = 1000;
  } else if (lightColour === fileArray[1]) {
    lightColour = "//placehold.it/50x50/3f0"; // green
    lightTimer = 5000;
  } else if (lightColour === fileArray[2]) {
    lightColour = "//placehold.it/50x50/f80"; // orange
    lightTimer = 1000;
  } else {
    lightColour = "//placehold.it/50x50/f00"; // red
    lightTimer = 5000;
  }

  light.src = lightColour

  // use setTimeout here instead
  setTimeout(lightChange, lightTimer);

}

lightChange(); // Start!!
```

```html
<h1>Changing Traffic Lights w/ Arrays</h1>

<img id="trafficLight" src="//placehold.it/50x50/f00">
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the value of 5000, remove the quotation marks around it.  If you set a variable to `"5000"`, the variable will be a string and not a number.  Removing the quotes will make it a number.

The code should look like this

`lightTimer = 5000;`

as apposed to

`lightTimer = "5000";`

Comment: Can you explain what's exactly wrong with a `"5000"` as string?

Comment: If you want it a string, its perfectly fine, but if it's _just_ a number, the variable can be easier manipulated if its a value.  And by the sounds of it, `"5000"` isn't working.

Comment: Well, setInterval can recognize a timeout parameter `"4000"` as *ms* so it does not matters at all.